# How to verify any kind of certificate in c/c++(openssl)?

Tags: c, linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, ca

I know how to verify a certificate

1. Load CA certificates by `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, caName, caPath)` or by creating `X509_STORE` and adding CA certificates to it.
2. Enable SSL client for peer verification by `SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL)`

By this way we can verify all certificates signed by loaded CA certificates.

What I want to know:

**1. Verify self signed certificate**

How to load multiple CA certificates by `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, caName, caPath)`?

How to provide caPath in mentioned function?

What I have tried:

- Created a soft ling for each CA certificate with name generated by command `openssl X509 -in ca_file.pem -noout -subject_hash`.
- These soft links are created in a same folder named *ca_path*
- Now, I pass this *ca_path* as `caPath` parameter in above function.

  I have tried to use different kind of names for soft links like `50693e.pem, 50693e.0, 50693e` according
  to hash generated, but nothing has worked.

**2. Verify a certificate signed by a well known CA**

Do I need to provide CA certificate bundle by myself for verification of even signed certificates?

Will openssl library fetch CA certificate chain from CertificateServer response during handshake, by itself(or I have 
   to do something)?

**3. How to enable ssl client to verify both kind(self signed and signed by a well known CA) of server certificates?**

Answer (score 0):

During SSL handshake, server certificate chain is verified,starting from host certificate till the last certificate which would be a self signed certificate.
eg Consider host certificate is server.cert,signed by intermediate certificate int.cert, signed by root certificate  ca.cert

During handshake, client asks for server certificate,server sends server.cert
Client verifies server.cert using int.cert, verifies int.cert with ca.cert and verifies ca.cert with ca.cert as its last certificate in chain and signed by itself
Whether you generate the certificate by yourself or get it from well known CA, it will always verify the entire certificate chain, unless you explicitly specify the depth of chain using SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth

For certificate verification to succeed you need to have setup int.cert and ca.cert at your client.
You can concatenate multiple CAs in single file(eg concat int.cert and ca.cert to form ca.pem) and load it using SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations, during handshake, certificates needed for verifying server.cert will be looked up from there.